# Changing permalinks woocoomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a webshop with filters in it. When I filter I get this as link:

https://royalkaarten.nl/winkel/Trouwkaarten/?swoof=1&pa_f=met-foto&really_curr_tax=51-product_cat

Is there any way to change this to https://royalkaarten.nl/trouwkaarten-metfoto

Comment: filter values comes from $_GET parameters.You wont be able to change it .But you can reprogram to get filter values via $_POST method.

Comment: How does that work?